# How do I get Ride Together Die Together?

Tags: borderlands-2

The Ride Together Die Together challenge requires me to kill "Tumbaa" and "Pimon" within 10 seconds of each other. There's extremely little info about this challenge on the internet (no videos, best I can tell) but they are apparently named bosses who do *not* always spawn, and if one spawns the other isn't always there. One is a Skag, the other is a Stalker.

They apparently spawn in the Wildlife Exploitation Preserve, *not* in the Natural Selection Annex ("creature slaughter dome"), so you don't need the DLC to reach it. What I do not know is *where* these bosses spawn or how common they are. I've been through the preserve at least 4-5 times and never noticed these bosses. Where are they and what do they look like?

Comment: I have seen Tumbaa just before the annex. He is a skag that is not much harder to kill than the regular skags and the only reason I noticed him was because of the name above him. I have seen him at least 3 times but never seen Pimon so idk how to beat the challenge either

Comment: Tumbaa is very easy to kill, I suggest using lobbed singularity grenades to pull everything together, a few of them should do, then I have a rocket launcher that shoots 3 at the same time and does fire damage. I used that to finish it all off.it helped being a few lvls above and having a good shield. I've yet to see pimon in 6 runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fought Pimon & Tumba both while on True Vault hunter mode. If I remember correctly *Pimon is a stalker & Tumbba is a skag*. They can also spawn in Normal Mode (Thanks, @SheDevil).

They appear on the field outside of preserve cells (where bloodwing was kept).

I will suggest weaken them both and take them down with a grenade or something.